# asp.net parser error - Could not load type 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication' after moving umbraco to shared hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I just moved an Umbraco 4.0.3 application to a shared hosting, with asp.net 4 classic mode.

i have copied all the source to the new location, uploaded the database and changed the connection string.
But i get the following parse error:

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type
>   'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Application Inherits="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication"
>   Language="C#" %> Line 2:
>
> Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1

[Here is a snapshot of the  error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIBep.png)

Comment: Have you ask your hosting provider to check it for you? Have you double check your connection string again?

Answer (score 1):

I had to rename the project locally from using 'umbraco' to resolve the same error.
http://jondjones.com/installing-umbraco-7-in-visual-studio-via-nuget/